# Unable to encrypt removable hard drive

Tags: macos, disk-utility, encryption, filevault, high-sierra

I have removable hard drive which I can't encrypt.

I'm following [official guide](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH22246?locale=en_US), but there is simply no encryption option in the erase menu:

[image]
There should also be an option called "Mac OS Extended (Journaled, Encrypted)", but it is not in the list.

To be more specific I'm running the latest update of OS X High Sierra (10.13.1). The hard drive model is: Transcend StoreJet 25M3 2TB TS2TSJ25M3E.

Comment: What's under 'Security Options'? What macOS version are you running?

Comment: @RushilSrivastava this options specify how to erase the disk, means how many times to override the information so it will not be recovered. I'm using  High Sierra 10.13.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was with GPT partition. Somehow the disk didn't have it.

After running the next command:

```
diskutil partitionDisk /dev/disk2 GPT JHFS+ New 0b
```

disk utility started offering needed encryption options.

`/dev/disk2` is the path of removable hard drive.

If you are not sure what is the path, run `diskutil list` - that will list all the disks and you'll be bale to pick yours.